# Invalid Form.Handle under Linux

Tags: winforms, mono, handle

I'am running mono v3.2.8 x64 under ArchLinux (Gnome 3) and noticed this strange behavior when crating a WinForm using this code:

```
namespace MWFTestApplication {
    class MainWindow : System.Windows.Forms.Form {  
        public MainWindow() {
            string hande = string.Format ("0x{0}", Handle.ToString ("x"));
            Console.WriteLine("Handle: " + hande);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Application.Run(new MainWindow());
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this under ArchLinux I can see the form but the result is like `Handle: 0x200000f` which obviously cant be right. I can recompile the application and start it again and the Handle does not change until I reboot. Then I get a new invalid Handle.
 When I run the same code under Windows I get a new random pointer for each run as expected.
My graphic card is a NVIDIA GTX 690 running driver version 334.21.